# how to implement the algorithm for the sum of the right digits and sum of left digits?

Tags: algorithm

A number is said to be cool number when the sum of its right digits is equal to the sum of its left digits. Can you please help me in building the logic for this question as I cannot build any logic for that

Comment: Please at least try to show you attempted something yourself.

Comment: Stackoverflow community is not for programming contest or homework kind of help. Please provide what you have done so far, if stuck then someone can help

Comment: Om Sao because I asked help beacuse i got stuck. If you ca'nt help then do not tell me what he community is for.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define what are left and right digits
2. Parse each digit on right, sum them
3. Parse each digit on left, sum them
4. check the sums are equal

If you have specific questions on each we can help, but we won't do your homework for you.